# Was ist korrekt? „Im Herzen Eins“ oder „Im Herzen eins“?

Tags: grammar

*Im Herzen Eins* oder *Im Herzen eins* – welche Schreibweise ist richtig?

Es soll als Spruch in Ringe graviert werden und die Verbindung der beiden Ringträger ausdrücken. Zwei Menschen, im Herzen eins (Eins?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In diesem Fall ist Kleinschreibung richtig, da es sich um [das Adjektiv](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/eins_zusammen_gleich) handelt: *Im Herzen eins.*

Comment: Vielen Dank! :)

Comment: @funksoulbr Wenn dir die Antwort geholfen hat, freuen sich die Fragesteller immer über das *Annehmen*: Unter den Stimmpfeilen ist ein kleiner grauer Haken, den du ergrünen lassen kannst ;) Diese Art des Bedankens wird lieber gesehen als Kommentare.